# Is it possible to find the modification time for a socket (or file), given the inode?

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

I have the inode of a socket - taken from /proc/net/tcp for example, and wish to find more data on that socket, specifically the creation or modification time.

I am working in C on linux (2.6 kernel).

This is similar to the question [Get file details by inode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305438/get-file-details-by-inode) - but that was from bash. The conclusion there is that there is no easy way, and relies on trawling directories for a match. I was hoping for something more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not.  The file creation time is not held, the three date/time stamps (see man 2 stat) held are the time of last access (atime), the time of last modification (mtime) and the time of the last file status change (ctime).

When the creation time is needed it is common practice to include it somewhere in the file name, obviously not an option with /proc/net/tcp.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I can probably get away with using the modification time, so I have edited the question to reflect this. My main issue it getting from an inode to an stat() type call.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "an inode to a stat()".  Note that stat is also available (on Linux) as a command-line program, so you can also use it from a script, and its a bit more friendly.  In C you get back the date/time stamps in number-of-seconds-since-epoc.  This is useful for comparisons and calculations.  Use localtime() or ctime() if you need to view it.

Comment: What I mean is "I have an inode" how do I get any time information about that file/socket? (Like I might get if I called stat() on a file by name.) Is there a way to do something like istat(inode, buf) ?

Comment: The first problem is that the filename is not held in the inode, it is held in the directory.  The second is that the inode number is not unique within a system, but only within the partition.  So there can be several files with the same inode number.  The third issue is that directory permissions are very important, so we must know the directory for many file operations.  To sum all that up, I do not know of a way of opening a file using just the inode number, and if there was I can see all kinds of issues.

Comment: There is also the issue of hard-links where multiple files point to the same inode..

Comment: @yi_H: I guess you mean multiple file names, an inode only refers to one physical file.  However I agree with the sentiment, do you want the creation date of each file name, or the original file, and what happens if it gets renamed?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that on the systems I investigated, there is little about time of socket creation or modification stored in an accessible manner.

It is possible to find the inode from the entries in /proc/net/tcp, and then search through all file handles in all the processes in /proc//fd for a match.

This doesn't really help though, as the time-stamps there appear to be when that directory is first accessed. i.e. the pseudo-directory is only created when it is queried.