# Python filename from inode?

Tags: python

I'm converting files from an old application on OS X. For reasons that must have been good at the time, it records associated files in its database by their inode numbers. (I think Apple calls it a FileID.)

Given a file name, I can find the inode in Python using os.stat(). But is there a Python way to find the name given an inode number?

Failing that, I can think of two other ways:

1. Scan all the files in the folder to collect all their inode numbers, and save them in a dictionary for quick reference.
2. Use os.system('find /folder/folder -inum 1234') and parse the output for what I am after. I suppose this does the same thing as above really, but done by the operating system.

I would prefer a Python native solution, but would be grateful for any other suggestions.

This will be Python2 on OS X 10.5 or 6.

Comment: Basically, given an inode number, there isn't a simple way to determine a name for the file.  Once upon a long time ago, 7th Edition Unix provided the tool `ncheck` to 'generate file names from file numbers' (it was a pre-cursor, with `icheck`, to the omnipotent `fsck`).  But that also involved scanning whole file systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [`volfs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11951944/484441) on OSX, but this might be actually slower than your *1.* approach.

Hence, I'd use your *1.* approach but with considering some important bits:

- An `inode` can point to **multiple** `files` (hardlinks).
- You'll have to make sure it's still the **same** device.

Your *2.* approach is basically the same as the first one, except with additional forking overhead and more importantly basically running the same costly enumeration again and again, instead of populating a map once.

Comment: I had not thought about the additional overhead of using 'find'. I suppose it depends on whether I am going to be looking up all the files on demand or only just a few. But parsing the output from find could be complicated depending on how many error messages are generated.

Comment: you don't have to look at the errors, because if there is a hit, it will be in stdout not stderr

Comment: @mnagel Then again you have to look at `stderr` to determine if there was an error (e.g. no permission to read a subdirectory) or if the `inode` just wasn't found when there was no hit.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you'll have to [bruteforce it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305438/get-file-details-by-inode). Filenames point to inodes. The inodes themselves don't contain a reference to the filename. Also you can have multiple hard links (locations in the file system, or file names) pointing to the same inode.

You can see [the elements of an inode struct](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ds/ds.html) on this page. Filename isn't there.

Comment: +1 The salient point (to my mind) is the fact that there may be more than one name linked to an inode. One isn't more "correct" than another. So OP needs a convention to determine which one is the name he wants.

Comment: Yes, I know there can be multiple links. However in this case, the way the files were created means that there will only be one link. It's actually even more complicated as some of the files no longer exist, and the inode may have been used for some other file in the meantime.